# Problems with Ajax and Trigger in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a Symfony application in which I have a table and each row in that table have a select to `select` a value and a `button` to launch an event with Jquery to save the data in the database.

The click event would be the next:

```
$(document).on('click',"#contenedor_registro_Ngrupos button",function(event){

// Here some checks are made (with ajax request) and if you can not change the value is added to select a class to indicate the error.

});
```

If I change the value of a `select` and click-on button, everything is done correctly. the data is saved or error is shown by the added class.

The problem I have to want to make a change at all and save all automatically. To do this I have created a `select` that to change, change the value to select all of the table, and also a `button` that should run all the buttons of the table.

I used "Trigger" to simulate click on all buttons of the table as follows:

```
$(document).on('click',"#button_all",function(event){
   $("contenedor_registro_Ngrupos select[class='modified']").each(function(){  
      $(this).closest("tr").find("button").trigger("click");
   });
});
```

But the problem I have is when running trigger and simulate the click, only adds the error to the last item to be displayed with the error, but the above will not be added. I tried with alert (); within the function to follow the process and standing execution to display alerts if added the wrong class, so I guess that will be problems implementing the Trigger in each, which does not give time for the simulation function is performed the click button.

I would like to know how I can solve this problem or if there is another way to run the click event of the buttons automatically without having to manually clicking on all buttons.

*HTML:

```
<div id="contenedor_registro_Ngrupos" class="derecha contenedor_registro">
 <div>
  <div id="cabecera_lista">
   <h2>Educación Infantil</h2>
  </div>

  <div>
    <table class="records_list">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th>Curso</th>
       <th>Nivel</th>
       <th>Nº Grupos</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   </table>

  <div class="inner_table">
    <table>
      <tbody> 
         <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="oculto">*</span>
            </td>
            <td>3 años</td>
            <td>Infantil</td>
            <td>
              <select id="Ngrupo">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
              </select>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <button>Guardar</button>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="oculto">*</span>
            </td>
            <td>4 años</td>
            <td>Infantil</td>
            <td>
              <select id="Ngrupo">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
              </select>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <button>Guardar</button>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>    //The same above code
          <tr>    //The same above code
          <tr>    //The same above code
          <tr>    //The same above code
         </tbody> 
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Images:

When selecting (Where you see a "3" should show a "1" to select that value, but inadvertently change before making image capture.And the three values "1" are in orange, previously had another value, and to change them is added the modified class that color.)

[image: When selecting]

When I click Save All("Guardar Todo" Button)

[image: When I click Save All("Guardar Todo" Button)]

When I click on save each button ("Guardar" Button)

[image: When I click on save each button ("Guardar" Button)]

The problem is not in the functions or selectors, the problem I have on how to call automatically to simulate a click on all buttons with the modified class, which is added previously in other functions.

Comment: Did you try `.click()`?

Comment: Hi @Praveen Kumar, I have not tried it. It is the same as trigger? I forgive my ignorance but I'm new at this.

Comment: I believe so. Try it out and let me know. Don't worry about ignorance and all. `:)`

Comment: Also try replacing the selector with `$("#container_table select.modified").`

Comment: I tried it and does the same, @Praveen Kumar.

Comment: Can you show us the full HTML as well? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I have not shown before because it creates symfony, but right now I'll show you the code in the symfony template and generated in .html.

Comment: I understand. Just the rendered HTML will do.

Comment: Woah... Can you make a snippet?

Comment: I added the Twig template code that generates the html, but is shown as html, and some images for you to understand what you should get and what I get. @Praveen Kumar

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, You mean if I can explain a little the process? Sorry I do not really understand the language.

Comment: In simple terms, not many have twig parsers in them. Browsers use HTML / CSS / JS. So if you can show us the rendered HTML and we can see if we can help. I am in my work PC and I neither have twig parser, nor I can install it.

Comment: I understand @Praveen Kumar, but it is difficult to put all the code here using Symfony. I have updated the code with html, but what I need is to know how I run several times an event of Jquery, maybe there is a better way than using Trigger. I supposed that Trigger run either the click event of each button and be displayed as in the third picture (which is manually by pressing each button) but it only shows the error in the last select (as you can see in the second photo)

Comment: Not sure. But did you get any errors in console? Sorry if I am repeating the question.

Comment: @Joseph, There is any ajax request fired on the button click?

Comment: Yes there is @Vicky R, to make some checks and to send data to store in the database.

Comment: @Joseph, once tried with option `jQuery.ajax({/***async:false ***/});` in `jQuery.ajax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery.ajax()**:- Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request. Ajax settings are A set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request.

> Ajax setting option -
>
> **async (default: true) :**
>
> *By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option
>   to **false**.*
>
> > Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

In your case you're trying to hit multiple request at time through trigger event. And due to this you are getting proper response from server to handle it.